# radius,center,plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do you determine the radius, center, and the plane containing the circle

$$r(t)=<\sin t ,0,4+\cos t>?$$

I tried:

$$R=\sqrt{(\sin t)^2+(4+\cos t)^2)} =\sqrt{\sin^2t+16+8\cos t+\cos^2t}
 =\sqrt{17+8\cos t}$$

how do  simplify this to get the radius?

Comment: There are many elements missing in your question... If this is an exercise please provide it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This circle lies in the $xz$ plane since the $y$ coordinates stay $0$. We can say that

$$x(t)=\sin(t), y(t)=0 \text{ and }z(t)=4+\cos(t).$$

In a coordinate plane $x'z'$ whose origin is the point $<0,4>$ the parametric equation is 
$$x'(t)=\sin(t),\ z'(t)=\cos(t).$$
So, 
$$x'^2+z'^2=1.$$

That is, we have a circle of radius $1$ in the $xz$ plane whose equation is

$$x^2+(z-4)^2=1.$$

Comment: so you translate the circle by adding <0,0,-4> first?

Comment: Yes. And by this I can observe the circle in the center of a new coordinate system. Then I push up the center of the circle to the point $(0,0,4).$

Answer (score 0):

So your circle lies in the plane having for equation $y=0$ and has for equation $x^2+(z-4)^2=1$. So its center is the point $(0,0,4)$ and its radius is equal to $1$.

Comment: how did you find x^2 + (z-4)^2-1?

Comment: Compute $x^2+(z-4)^2$.